# Were marriage certificates, granted after banns, recorded?

Tags: marriage-practices, marriage-records, wales

In the groom's parish of Bagillt, Flintshire, Wales, the [marriage banns](http://search.findmypast.com/record?id=gbprs/wal/4363414/00025&parentid=gbprs/m/885016804/1&highlights=%22%22) was recorded. At the bottom it says "Certificate granted Sept 14th 1835". Would a copy of that certificate have been recorded? What would the certificate say? Is there value in searching for it?

The [marriage was recorded](http://search.findmypast.com/record?id=gbprs/wal/4631238/00031&parentid=gbprs/m/880020687/1&highlights=%22%22) in the bride's parish of Llanferras, Denbighshire, Wales but I can't find record of the banns. I'm hoping to find a marriage record which mentions the names of the groom's parents and the certificate mentioned in the banns from Bagillt is my next idea.

Comment: My usual approach would be to find the couple in the censuses - there are candidate couples in Hope, Flintshire in the 1851 and 1861 census - and then look for candidate baptisms in their areas of origin. Unfortunately, he claims to be born in Hope in the 1851 and Gresford (Denbighshire) in the 1861. She's born in Hope in both cases, so is simpler. My *inclination* is that I'd prioritise looking for Charles (*if* it's the right family) in Gresford on the basis that in 1851, someone wrote "Hope" for everyone.  You may well have done this already and discovered multiple candidates for Charles?

Comment: @AdrianB38 I have been down that route. We have two candidate baptisms.

Comment: JustinY, have you tried tracing the individual in each of those baptisms forward to try to eliminate one or both of them?

Comment: @JustinY: "We have two candidate baptisms". I was afraid of that. I thought it was worth indicating my methodology because I wasn't sure how much experience you had of our records of that era but, as I did a rough search myself, I began to suspect that you'd already been down that road. And looking at my map, it also seems like all the candidate's parishes are pretty much adjacent. Oh dear...

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl We might have, once. This is the sort of problem person we come back to every 6 months. I think I'll try it again though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nowhere that a copy of that certificate would have been recorded.

Whether or not parents names were recorded in Parish Marriage or Banns Registers in England and Wales before 1837 varied widely -- there was no requirement to do so, so it was dependent on the whim of the parish incumbent.  From the start of Civil Registration in 1837, father's names and occupations were recorded but even today there is no requirement to record details of mothers.

Comment: I would *guess* that the sole function of that certificate is just to certify to the minister at Llanferras that the banns had been read at Bagillt. Hence there would be no need for detail above and beyond that written in the record of the banns.